# Why is a certain part of my table italicised?

Tags: tables, italic

I am just wondering why, in the following table, the words "Male" and "Black" are italicised, while Quintile 3 isn't? I'd like Quintile 3 to be italicised, but I don't know why "Male" and "Black" are italicised in the first place...

[image]

My code for the table is below (I haven't posted an MWE because I think the problem must be contained within this code):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\caption{Regression Results}
\label{table:RegressionResults}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
!{\extracolsep{\fill}}
p{0.23\textwidth}
*{7}{S[table-format=2.5, table-align-text-post=false, parse-numbers=false]}
}
\toprule
{\bfseries\small Variable} & {\bfseries\small Base} & {\bfseries\small All}  & {\bfseries\small Commerce} & {\bfseries\small B.Bus.Sci} &      {\bfseries\small BCom} & {\bfseries\small EBE} & {\bfseries\small Science} \\
\midrule
{\small Female} & Male & {\small 1.953\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl}} &   {\small 1.711\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl}} &  1.626\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.617\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.005 & 1.793\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
 & & {\small(0.137)} & {\small(0.194)} & (0.269) & (0.269) & (0.162) & (0.253) \\
{\small Age} && 1.010 & 0.920 & 0.761\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.288\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.066 & 1.072 \\
 & & (0.039) & (0.065) & (0.071) & (0.160) & (0.080) & (0.075) \\
Coloured & Black & 1.099 & 1.122 & 1.482 & 0.774 & 1.048 & 1.276 \\
& & (0.186) & (0.327) & (0.600) & (0.340) & (0.354) & (0.461) \\
Indian/Asian & Black & 0.670\textsuperscript{\textdagger} &  0.488\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.021 &   0.337\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  0.565\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.947 \\
& & (0.114) & (0.137) & (0.443) & (0.137) & (0.187) & (0.384) \\
White & Black & 5.123\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  2.953\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 3.510\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 2.679\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 4.748\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 12.548\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
& & (0.841) & (0.817) & (1.361) & (1.112) & (1.465) & (4.620) \\
Financial Aid && 0.678\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  0.397\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.420\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.400\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.754\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.706\textsuperscript{\textdagger} \\
 & &(0.056) & (0.054) & (0.077) & (0.081) & (0.129) & (0.118) \\
\multirow{2}{30mm}{Academic Development} && 0.911 & 0.930 & 1.116 & 0.783 & 0.897 & 0.574\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
 & & (0.083) & (0.132) & (0.211) & (0.175) & (0.184) & (0.124) \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{30mm}{English Home Language} && 1.401\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.716\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.472 & 2.265\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.739\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.293 \\
& & (0.208) & (0.433) & (0.512) & (0.864) & (0.493) & (0.418) \\
\addlinespace
{\small School Quintile 1} & {Quintile 3}& 1.016 & 1.051 & 1.250 & 0.516 & 0.794 & 1.469 \\
& & (0.244) & (0.456) & (0.610) & (0.783) & (0.375) & (0.627) \\
{\small School Quintile 2} & {Quintile 3}& 1.291 & 1.161 & 0.966 & 1.653 &  1.846\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.968 \\
& & (0.242) & (0.449) & (0.455) & (1.175) & (0.634) & (0.307) \\
{\small School Quintile 4} & {Quintile 3}& 0.920 & 0.771 & 0.818 & 0.559 & 0.827 & 0.744 \\
&& (0.140) & (0.211) & (0.276) & (0.287) & (0.252) & (0.206) \\
{\small School Quintile 5} & {Quintile 3}& 1.760\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl}   & 1.351 & 1.412 & 1.616 & 1.845\textsuperscript{\textdagger} &  1.527\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} \\
 & & (0.218) & (0.301) & (0.390) & (0.687) & (0.465) & (0.362) \\
Independent & {\small Quintile 3}& 1.663\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.203 & 1.312 & 1.626 & 1.789\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.335 \\
 & & (0.219) & (0.284) & (0.399) & (0.708) & (0.472) & (0.338) \\
Western Cape && 1.145 & 1.275\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.144 & 1.661\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.073 & 0.950 \\
& &  (0.099) & (0.183) & (0.235) & (0.358) & (0.192) & (0.167) \\
Grade 12 GPA && 1.119\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  1.119\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.156\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.111\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.148\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.134\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
 && (0.007) & (0.011) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) \\
Mathematics Mark && 1.007\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.012\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.005 & 1.048\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.054\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.022\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
&& (0.003) & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.008) & (0.006) \\
English Mark && 1.013\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.012 & 1.006 & 1.038\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.007 & 1.003 \\
&& (0.004) & (0.008) & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.008) \\
Science && --- & 1.053 & 1.352\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.239 & ---  & 1.252 \\
& &  & (0.136) & (0.233) & (0.255) &  & (0.557) \\
Residence && 1.117 & 1.401\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.240 & 1.061 & 1.019 & 0.937 \\
& & (0.102) & (0.209) & (0.259) & (0.238) & (0.195) & (0.169) \\
\midrule
Controls for Time && {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
Observations && {36 333} & {20 409}  &{7 408}    & {13 001}  & {9 169}&  {6 755} \\
Pseudo \(R^{2}\) && {0.397} & {0.451} & {0.420} & {0.574} & {0.419} & {0.431} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.05\), \textsuperscript{\textdagger}   \(p<0.01\), \textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why is the second column declared as `S`?

Comment: I'm sure you could reduce this to a more readable example..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've set the column type for the second column to `S` even though there are no numbers to be aligned on decimal points in that column. Some entries in that column -- such as "Male" and "Black" -- thus show up in math italics; other entries, such as "Quintile 3", have been encased in curly braces and are therefore treated as centered text by the syntax rules of the `siunitx` package. I suggest you use a simple `l` column type for the second column.

There are a lot of redundant `\small` statements in your code; do get rid of them. To get `---` in an `S` column to be typeset as a centered em-dash rather than as three separate minus symbols, encase it in curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set page margins to suit your needs
\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.5, 
         table-align-text-post=false, 
         parse-numbers=false}

\captionsetup{font=small} % same font size for caption as as rest of table
\caption{Regression Results} 
\label{table:RegressionResults}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{6}{S} }
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Base} 
& {\bfseries All}  & {\bfseries Commerce} & {\bfseries B.Bus.Sci} 
& {\bfseries BCom} & {\bfseries EBE} & {\bfseries Science} \\
\midrule
Female & Male & 1.953\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &   1.711\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  1.626\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.617\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.005 & 1.793\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
 & & (0.137) & (0.194) & (0.269) & (0.269) & (0.162) & (0.253) \\
Age && 1.010 & 0.920 & 0.761\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.288\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.066 & 1.072 \\
 & & (0.039) & (0.065) & (0.071) & (0.160) & (0.080) & (0.075) \\
Coloured & Black & 1.099 & 1.122 & 1.482 & 0.774 & 1.048 & 1.276 \\
& & (0.186) & (0.327) & (0.600) & (0.340) & (0.354) & (0.461) \\
Indian/Asian & Black & 0.670\textsuperscript{\textdagger} &  0.488\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.021 &   0.337\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  0.565\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.947 \\
& & (0.114) & (0.137) & (0.443) & (0.137) & (0.187) & (0.384) \\
White & Black & 5.123\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  2.953\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 3.510\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 2.679\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 4.748\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 12.548\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
& & (0.841) & (0.817) & (1.361) & (1.112) & (1.465) & (4.620) \\
Financial Aid && 0.678\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  0.397\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.420\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.400\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 0.754\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.706\textsuperscript{\textdagger} \\
 & &(0.056) & (0.054) & (0.077) & (0.081) & (0.129) & (0.118) \\
Academic && 0.911 & 0.930 & 1.116 & 0.783 & 0.897 & 0.574\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
Development & & (0.083) & (0.132) & (0.211) & (0.175) & (0.184) & (0.124) \\
\addlinespace
English Home && 1.401\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.716\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.472 & 2.265\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.739\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.293 \\
Language& & (0.208) & (0.433) & (0.512) & (0.864) & (0.493) & (0.418) \\
\addlinespace
School Quintile 1 & Quintile 3& 1.016 & 1.051 & 1.250 & 0.516 & 0.794 & 1.469 \\
& & (0.244) & (0.456) & (0.610) & (0.783) & (0.375) & (0.627) \\
School Quintile 2 & Quintile 3& 1.291 & 1.161 & 0.966 & 1.653 &  1.846\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 0.968 \\
& & (0.242) & (0.449) & (0.455) & (1.175) & (0.634) & (0.307) \\
School Quintile 4 & Quintile 3& 0.920 & 0.771 & 0.818 & 0.559 & 0.827 & 0.744 \\
&& (0.140) & (0.211) & (0.276) & (0.287) & (0.252) & (0.206) \\
School Quintile 5 & Quintile 3& 1.760\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl}   & 1.351 & 1.412 & 1.616 & 1.845\textsuperscript{\textdagger} &  1.527\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} \\
 & & (0.218) & (0.301) & (0.390) & (0.687) & (0.465) & (0.362) \\
Independent & Quintile 3& 1.663\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.203 & 1.312 & 1.626 & 1.789\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.335 \\
 & & (0.219) & (0.284) & (0.399) & (0.708) & (0.472) & (0.338) \\
Western Cape && 1.145 & 1.275\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.144 & 1.661\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.073 & 0.950 \\
& &  (0.099) & (0.183) & (0.235) & (0.358) & (0.192) & (0.167) \\
Grade 12 GPA && 1.119\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} &  1.119\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.156\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.111\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.148\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.134\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
 && (0.007) & (0.011) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) \\
Mathematics Mark && 1.007\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.012\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.005 & 1.048\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.054\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.022\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \\
&& (0.003) & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.008) & (0.006) \\
English Mark && 1.013\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.012 & 1.006 & 1.038\textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} & 1.007 & 1.003 \\
&& (0.004) & (0.008) & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.008) \\
Science && --- & 1.053 & 1.352\textsuperscript{\textasteriskcentered} & 1.239 & ---  & 1.252 \\
& &  & (0.136) & (0.233) & (0.255) &  & (0.557) \\
Residence && 1.117 & 1.401\textsuperscript{\textdagger} & 1.240 & 1.061 & 1.019 & 0.937 \\
& & (0.102) & (0.209) & (0.259) & (0.238) & (0.195) & (0.169) \\
\midrule
Controls for Time && {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
Observations && {36 333} & {20 409}  &{7 408}    & {13 001}  & {9 169}&  {6 755} \\
Pseudo \(R^{2}\) && {0.397} & {0.451} & {0.420} & {0.574} & {0.419} & {0.431} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.05\), \textsuperscript{\textdagger}   \(p<0.01\), \textsuperscript{\textdaggerdbl} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second column has been declared as `S`, which it isn't.

You're also not consistent in bracing the items. There are many simplifications you can do for easing input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}

\newcommand{\noteg}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\newcommand{\notea}{\noteg{\textasteriskcentered}}
\newcommand{\noted}{\noteg{\textdagger}}
\newcommand{\notedd}{\noteg{\textdaggerdbl}}
\newcommand{\doublerow}[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\caption{Regression Results}
\label{table:RegressionResults}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  !{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  ll
  *{6}{
   S[
     table-format=2.4,
     table-align-text-post=false,
     parse-numbers=false,
   ]
  }
}
\toprule
{\bfseries Variable} & {\bfseries Base} & {\bfseries All}  & {\bfseries Commerce} & {\bfseries B.Bus.Sci} &      {\bfseries BCom} & {\bfseries EBE} & {\bfseries Science} \\
\midrule
Female & Male & 1.953\notedd & 1.711\notedd &  1.626\notedd & 1.617\notedd & 1.005 & 1.793\notedd \\
       &      & (0.137) & (0.194) & (0.269) & (0.269) & (0.162) & (0.253) \\
Age && 1.010 & 0.920 & 0.761\notedd & 1.288\noted & 1.066 & 1.072 \\
 & & (0.039) & (0.065) & (0.071) & (0.160) & (0.080) & (0.075) \\
Coloured & Black & 1.099 & 1.122 & 1.482 & 0.774 & 1.048 & 1.276 \\
& & (0.186) & (0.327) & (0.600) & (0.340) & (0.354) & (0.461) \\
Indian/Asian & Black & 0.670\noted &  0.488\noted & 1.021 &   0.337\notedd &  0.565\notea & 0.947 \\
& & (0.114) & (0.137) & (0.443) & (0.137) & (0.187) & (0.384) \\
White & Black & 5.123\notedd &  2.953\notedd & 3.510\notedd & 2.679\noted & 4.748\notedd & 12.548\notedd \\
& & (0.841) & (0.817) & (1.361) & (1.112) & (1.465) & (4.620) \\
Financial Aid && 0.678\notedd &  0.397\notedd & 0.420\notedd & 0.400\notedd & 0.754\notea & 0.706\noted \\
 & &(0.056) & (0.054) & (0.077) & (0.081) & (0.129) & (0.118) \\
\doublerow{Academic \\ Development} && 0.911 & 0.930 & 1.116 & 0.783 & 0.897 & 0.574\notedd \\
 & & (0.083) & (0.132) & (0.211) & (0.175) & (0.184) & (0.124) \\
\addlinespace
\doublerow{English Home \\ Language} && 1.401\noted & 1.716\notedd & 1.472 & 2.265\notedd & 1.739\notea & 1.293 \\
& & (0.208) & (0.433) & (0.512) & (0.864) & (0.493) & (0.418) \\
\addlinespace
School Quintile 1 & Quintile 3 & 1.016 & 1.051 & 1.250 & 0.516 & 0.794 & 1.469 \\
& & (0.244) & (0.456) & (0.610) & (0.783) & (0.375) & (0.627) \\
School Quintile 2 & Quintile 3 & 1.291 & 1.161 & 0.966 & 1.653 &  1.846\notea & 0.968 \\
& & (0.242) & (0.449) & (0.455) & (1.175) & (0.634) & (0.307) \\
School Quintile 4 & Quintile 3 & 0.920 & 0.771 & 0.818 & 0.559 & 0.827 & 0.744 \\
&& (0.140) & (0.211) & (0.276) & (0.287) & (0.252) & (0.206) \\
School Quintile 5 & Quintile 3 & 1.760\notedd   & 1.351 & 1.412 & 1.616 & 1.845\noted &  1.527\notea \\
 & & (0.218) & (0.301) & (0.390) & (0.687) & (0.465) & (0.362) \\
Independent & Quintile 3 & 1.663\notedd & 1.203 & 1.312 & 1.626 & 1.789\noted & 1.335 \\
 & & (0.219) & (0.284) & (0.399) & (0.708) & (0.472) & (0.338) \\
Western Cape && 1.145 & 1.275\notea & 1.144 & 1.661\noted & 1.073 & 0.950 \\
& &  (0.099) & (0.183) & (0.235) & (0.358) & (0.192) & (0.167) \\
Grade 12 GPA && 1.119\notedd &  1.119\notedd & 1.156\notedd & 1.111\notedd & 1.148\notedd & 1.134\notedd \\
 && (0.007) & (0.011) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) \\
Mathematics Mark && 1.007\noted & 1.012\noted & 1.005 & 1.048\notedd & 1.054\notedd & 1.022\notedd \\
&& (0.003) & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.008) & (0.006) \\
English Mark && 1.013\notedd & 1.012 & 1.006 & 1.038\notedd & 1.007 & 1.003 \\
&& (0.004) & (0.008) & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.008) \\
Science && {---} & 1.053 & 1.352\notea & 1.239 & {---}  & 1.252 \\
& &  & (0.136) & (0.233) & (0.255) &  & (0.557) \\
Residence && 1.117 & 1.401\noted & 1.240 & 1.061 & 1.019 & 0.937 \\
& & (0.102) & (0.209) & (0.259) & (0.238) & (0.195) & (0.169) \\
\midrule
Controls for Time && {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
Observations && {36\,333} & {20\,409}  & {7\,408}    & {13\,001}  & {9\,169}&  {6\,755} \\
Pseudo \(R^{2}\) && {0.397} & {0.451} & {0.420} & {0.574} & {0.419} & {0.431} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \notea\ \ \(p<0.05\), \noted\ \ \(p<0.01\), \notedd\ \ \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]